# Sometimes the jumping mechanic doesnt work

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, 2d

recently I started working on a 2d Unity local coop platformer game, with a simple code of movement. The problem is that sometimes when I try to jump it doesnt work, its not a keyboard problem, I tried in different computers.

Heres the code:

````
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Player1Movement : MonoBehaviour
{
    //Movement

    public float speed;
    public float jump;
    float moveVelocity;
    public Rigidbody2D rb;
    bool isGrounded;

    void Update()
    {
        //Grounded?
        if (isGrounded == true)
        {
            //jumping
            if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.W))
            {

                GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().velocity = new Vector2(GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().velocity.x, jump);
            }

        }

        moveVelocity = 0;

        //Left Right Movement
        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.A))
        {
            moveVelocity = -speed;
        }
        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.D))
        {
            moveVelocity = speed;
        }

        GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().velocity = new Vector2(moveVelocity, GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().velocity.y);

    }
    void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D col)
    {
        Debug.Log("OnCollisionEnter2D");
        isGrounded = true;
    }
    void OnCollisionExit2D(Collision2D col)
    {
        Debug.Log("OnCollisionExit2D");
        isGrounded = false;
    }
}```
````

Comment: call `GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>` in `Awake` then save the result to a `private Rigidbody2D rb2d;` field so you don't have to call it multiple times during each `Update`. It's not a fast operation so you don't want to call it every frame especially multiple times.

Answer (score 0):

If you take this code

```
//jumping
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.W))
        {

            GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().velocity = new 
Vector2(GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().velocity.x, jump);
        }
```

Out of the isGrounded if statement, does the jump work consistently? If so, the issue is with your isGrounded logic.

As for the ground check, I would switch to a raycast approach as, assuming you're using tiles, you will be flicking off and on isGrounded as you move between tiles.

Also, to increase performance, if you add this into an awake function

```
 Rb = GetComponent<RigidBody2D>();
```

And replace all of your getcomponents with rb.